# Can I access to the real path of a symbolic link in nautilus without scripts or terminal?

Tags: symlink, nautilus

I made a symbolic link to a folder using the command `ln`. This link is located in my Desktop folder, the path of this link is as follows:

`/home/user/Desktop/workspace/`

The real path is:

`/home/user2/folder1/folder2/workspace/`

I know how to access the real path using terminal, and I know how to make scripts and open it using nautilus or other applications.

I have a theoretical question: 
Can I access to the workspace path with nautilus, without commands or scripts, using the symbolic link? Is nautilus prepared to provide this function?

Comment: No but you can always write your own extension that does that... (example: [open-the-link-target-in-nautilus](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1007593/))

Comment: 4 years later and still no implementation for what seems a basic and useful feature?